# Can I instantly print information to the database when sessions close when the user closes the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a project that I am developing with php. When users log off, the query runs on the MYSQL database, for example: status = 'offline'. But I also want to do this when the user closes the browser. For example, I want to update the query in the MYSQL database instantly when the user is disconnected from the server when the user's computer suddenly shuts down, such as status = 'offline'. To illustrate this, you're texting someone via facebook. The other person's computer suddenly shuts down and, after 1 minute, he is writing offline at the top of the conversation. I want to do something like this, I've tried various methods but failed. I'm new to PHP, can you help me in detail?

Comment: why when closing the browser not the window or when he logout ?

Comment: You can't do this with just PHP, PHP is a server side language meaning it can't really know when your user is active or not. Make some JavaScript which updates a cell in your database every minute with the current timestamp, if the timestamp ever gets over a minute old, you know the user isn't online. You could take this a step further, say you have some JavaScript funciton which updates a cell every 60 seconds, in this function you could check if the user has had any activity (moving mouse, etc) before updating the cell.

Comment: But JavaScript client side. If the user changes mouse gesture, keyboard gesture, or page before closing the browser, it will appear online. What if the user closes the browser immediately after making these actions? Then you cannot update JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution maybe to update some field in DB saving the most recent user's activity time. It can be done simply by updating this field on every request from client. 
Than you can consider user as "offline" in case of not receiving updates within X minutes since the last update.

You can also add some client side code which will send background "keep alive" requests once in a while to inform server that client is still there.